# Add libConfuse to eclipse [c][cross compilation]

Tags: c, eclipse, cross-compiling

Hi I try to access a configuration file using libConfuse.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <confuse.h>

#include "core.h"
#include "readconfig.h"

int read_config_file(const char * filename, struct damterm_socket *dt_sock){

    cfg_t *cfg;

    cfg_opt_t socket_opts[] = {
            CFG_STR("destination_ip", IP_ADDR_DEFAULT, CFGF_NONE),
            CFG_INT("port", PORT_DEFAULT, CFGF_NONE),
            CFG_END()
        };
    cfg = cfg_init(socket_opts, CFGF_NONE);
    if(cfg_parse(cfg, filename) == CFG_PARSE_ERROR)
        printf("Błąd parsowania pliku!\n");
    else if(cfg_parse(cfg, filename) == CFG_FILE_ERROR)
        printf("Bład odczytu pliku\n"); //!TODO check existing of the file if not create new one.


    return -1; //!TODO Do nothing, return error.
}
```

And error from Eclipse:

```
readconfig.c:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `cfg_init'
readconfig.c:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `cfg_parse'
readconfig.c:(.text+0x8c): undefined reference to `cfg_parse'
```

I have add /usr/local/lib in:
Properties>Settings>Includes (-I) **and**
Properties>Settings>Libraries (-L)
after that the error is:

```
/home/sylwek/iGT/OpenWrt-SDK-mr-mips-for-linux-i686-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/bin/../lib/gcc/mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/4.6.3/../../../../mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libconfuse.so when searching for -lconfuse
makefile:29: polecenia dla obiektu 'mips' nie powiodły się
/home/sylwek/iGT/OpenWrt-SDK-mr-mips-for-linux-i686-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/bin/../lib/gcc/mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/4.6.3/../../../../mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libconfuse.a when searching for -lconfuse

/home/sylwek/iGT/OpenWrt-SDK-mr-mips-for-linux-i686-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/bin/../lib/gcc/mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/4.6.3/../../../../mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libconfuse.so when searching for -lconfuse
/home/sylwek/iGT/OpenWrt-SDK-mr-mips-for-linux-i686-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/bin/../lib/gcc/mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/4.6.3/../../../../mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: cannot find -lconfuse
/home/sylwek/iGT/OpenWrt-SDK-mr-mips-for-linux-i686-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/bin/../lib/gcc/mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/4.6.3/../../../../mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 when searching for libgcc_s.so.1
```

Here is a note from installation file:

```
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the '-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the '-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to '/etc/ld.so.conf'
```

I also tried add confuse to (-l) but have error that it can't be find:

```
ls -l /usr/local/lib/libconfuse.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 05-31 13:22 /usr/local/lib/libconfuse.so -> libconfuse.so.1.0.0
```

I hope I give enough information and somebody can help me.
P.S. I do cross compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing compiler options:

- `-L` add a path for libraries
- `-I` add a path for includes
- `-l(libname)` add a specific compiled library to be linked to

`undefined reference to` is a linking error. So you are not adding the lib.

At least add `-L/usr/local/lib -lconfuse` to your command

BTW you should add /usr/local/lib to library search path by default adding the path to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and launching `ldconfig` command.

Comment: Now I think it can be caused by cross compilation? I don't have a libconfuse.so for my cross compilation platform? What do you think?

Comment: If you are cross compiling you need the cross compiled library into your SDK.

Comment: I am new in the cross compilation. It will be enough if I just import libConfuse as shared library and add it in Properties>Project References?

Comment: You must learn something about it. To cross compile you need, at least a cross compiler. This compiler is designed to compile code that can be executed on your target architecture. So all libs that you want to link to your project must be compiled with the same/compatible cross compiler. Those kind of libraries are usually deployed with SDK (Software Development Kit). If you haven't got the libs into SDK you can: 1) download the source code of lib and cross compile it by yourself. 2) DDownload a compatible cross compiled library.

Comment: I don't know how Eclipse project is configured in your case. I used to use autotool to ceate cross compiled application.

Comment: I have cross compilation and understood how it works (generally I still learn), I write a simple application that worked on my target machine. But now I would like to read config file and I don't know how to compile somebody's lib in Eclipse. But it's not the subject of this question. If you have a good link where I can read about it I would be nice. Sorry for my English if was bad.

Comment: It is a very huge matter, and there are tons of materials on the web. So you should start searching guide for your specific target. What is your target CPU/MCU?

Comment: Generally Atheroes 9xxx and 7xxx.

Comment: [This can help you?](https://developer.qualcomm.com/software/snapdragon-sdk-android/quick-start-guide) It is always a good starting point to look for resources on vendor sites.

Comment: I have problem with libConfuse because it use autogen something.. But I will manage it, I must! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As @LPs answered:

> If you are cross compiling you need the cross compiled library into your SDK.